# Consulta en mysql (nesesito ayuda)

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente problema:

en una base de datos mysql necesito una lista de todos los datos de la tabla category mas los de otra consulta 
[image]
nesesito listar los datos de category.category__id , category.category__name, (y la cantidad de comentarios que tiene esa categoria agrupando lo que corresponda para que solo cuente un comentario no todos los comentarios del mismo usuario)

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor, seria bueno que agregues lo que has intentado y de ser posible un ejemplo concreto con el resultado esperado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Siempre se pide que muestres lo que intentaste, si no parece que lo estuvieramos haciendo por vos ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW vista AS
SELECT category_id, category_name, CONCAT(comments.comments_user_id,"/",comments_category) as x
FROM category
INNER JOIN comments
ON category_id = comments_category
GROUP BY x;

SELECT category_id, category_name, count(category_id)
FROM vista
GROUP BY category_id
```